# Problem with Image-Dired: image display does not follow point in the thumbnail buffer

Tags: image-dired

I typed "C-t d" after marking files in Dired, or "M-x image-dired" followed by a directory name, to display thumbnails in a thumbnail buffer. After highlighting a thumbnail in the thumbnail buffer, I typed RET to display a sized version of highlighted image in another window (image-dired-display-image). The problem is that no matter what image is selected in the thumbnail buffer (either using the left/right arrow followed by RET, or using space/backspace, as instructed in the Emacs manual), the display-image window always displays the same image, which is the image opened first in this way in an Emacs session.

Comment: Upvoted because I didn't even know this bit of awesomeness existed :) I can't replicate the problem, though. Which version of Emacs are you using? Does the same thing happen when you start from `emacs -Q` ?

Comment: Have you enabled debugging -- `(setq debug-on-error t)` -- and also checked your `*Messages*` buffer for any error messages or clues?  Is the binary `convert` in your Emacs executable path?  Mine is working as it should, so we need some more clues to help diagnose your issue.  If you use the `C-u` prefix before pressing the `RET` key, can you display the full-size image reliably?  As you move the cursor from one thumbnail to the next, can you see messages in the echo-area with the image file names changing as you move?  [The file names should be changing as you move the cursor.]

Comment: @lawlist Thanks for the suggestions. The debugger does not return any error, and the filename of the file highlighted in the thumbnail buffer is properly displayed in the minibuffer, although the display-image window seems to be stuck with the same image. Finally I upgrade my Emacs from 24.4 to 24.5, and the problem is gone now! (I built Emacs from source on Mac OS X.)  Thanks again for commenting.

Comment: @phils Thanks for letting me know it is possible to run emacs -Q, which I was not aware of before.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading Emacs from 24.4 to 24.5 solves the problem, although I am not sure what is wrong with my built of Emacs 24.4. (I compiled both versions of Emacs from source on Mac OS X Yosemite.)